Tradeoff between autocorrelation and memory in a GLMM
I am working with a large dataframe in R. It is a BACI design (Before-After-Control-Impact). I am interested in seeing if the interaction between Treatment (0 = control, 1 = impact) and Period (Before, After) is significant. This dataset was collected over a long period of time (6 years) with measurements collected every half hour. Because of the nature of the specific question I am asking, I have to stick with those half-hour measurements. The issue is that there is autocorrelation between the measurements, but whenever I try to include an autocorrelation function within the generalized linear mixed model I am using, R says that there isn't enough memory space. The model that has shown to be the best using AIC, residuals, and autocorrelation plots has much less autocorrelation than it originally had. Looking at the plot below, is this still a problem? I have a feeling the autocorrelation is too big to ignore, but this means I'll have to switch to another type of statistic because I can't create an autocorrelation function for the GLMM.
Here is the model below. Please note that Connectivity is either a 0 or a 1 (it is 0 much more often). And I have tried simplifying the model down to nothing except for the interaction between Treatment and Period and an autocorrelation term and the memory still fails. The model does not perform as well (AIC and residual plots) if I do not include the additional terms. Any recommendations will be appreciated.
glmmTMB_model_interaction_sub_gw <- glmmTMB(
  Connectivity ~ Treatment * Period + (1 | Subwatershed) + Half_hourly_Average + 
    corrected_seasonal_mm_half_hour_avg + Year,
  family = binomial(link = "logit"),
  data = data
)



If memory is the main concern, see my answer here for reducing the memory footprint of GLMMs.
